# ''Differential equation'' with known solution $\sin$ and $\cos$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

I am given the following two two equations

> $f,g : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ are differentiable on $\mathbb{R}$ and they satisfy $\forall x,y \in \mathbb{R}$ $$f(x+y) = f(x)g(y)+f(y)g(x)\\g(x+y)=g(x)g(y)-f(x)f(y)  $$ with $f(-x)=-f(x), \forall x \in \mathbb{R}$ and $f'(0)=1$.

I want to show that $f= \sin$ and $g = \cos$

**My approach**: My general idea was to show that $$f'=g, \  g'=-f$$ and $$f(0)=0, \ g(0)=1$$

If I'd manage to do that, then the solution follows because the above differential equation has unique solution $f= \sin, g = \cos$.

---

Since $f$ is an 'uneven' function it follows that $f(0)=-f(0) \implies f(0)=0$ so that's one check out of the above list $\checkmark$

Differentiating the first given expression I'd obtain $$f'(x+y)=f'(x)g(y)+f(y)g'(x) \implies f'(0)=f'(0)g(0)+f(0)g'(0)=g(0)=1 $$ 
So that takes care of $g(0)=1 \ \checkmark$

Now to the tricky part. I will differentiate both equations and obtain: $$f'(x+y)=f'(x)g(y) + f(y) g'(x) \\ g'(x+y)=g'(x)g(y)-f'(x)f(y) $$
It seems like it is crucial that $g'(0)=0$ in order to show the remaining two properties out of my list above. Which so far I didn't manage to do because all my steps are circular: $$f'(y)= f'(0)g(y)+f(y)g'(0)=g(y)+f(y)g'(0) \tag{*} $$
which would only help me if $g'(0)=0$, similarly $$g'(y)=g'(0)g(y)-f'(0)f(y)=g'(0)g(y)-f(y) $$

Which doesn't help me either, maybe there is a substitution I have to perform but I yet fail to see it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you can note that $$0=f(x-x)=f(x)g(-x)+f(-x)g(x)=f(x)g(-x)-f(x)g(x)=f(x)\bigl[g(x)-g(-x)\bigr].$$ This holds for all $x\in\Bbb R,$ and since $f'(0)\ne 0,$ then $f$ isn't the constant zero function. It follows that $g(x)=g(-x)$ whenever $f(x)\ne 0.$ In particular $f$ is non-zero in some punctured neighborhood about $x=0$ (why?), and clearly $g(0)=g(-0),$ so for all $x$ sufficiently close to $0,$ we have $g(x)=g(-x).$ From this, you can show that $g'(0)=0$ directly, using a [symmetric derivative](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_derivative).

Comment: To answer your question forwarded to me. Since $f'(0) \neq 0$ we know that $f(x) \neq 0$ in a neighborhood around $x=0$ because with $f$ being differentiable at said point it means that it is continuous there as well. Hence $f$ is continuous in said neighborhood and therefore it must remain positive there.

Comment: In general I believe that your result follows very elegantly if your expression is differentiated. We'd obtain $$0=f'(x)[g(x)-g(-x)]+f(x)[g'(x)+g'(-x)] $$ evaluated at zero , the left hand side vanishes and $f'(0) \neq 0$ as you said, thus $g(x)=g(-x)$

Comment: Not quite. Rather, $f(x)\ne 0$ in a *punctured* neighborhood about $x=0,$ since we already know that $f(0)=0.$ Also, we can't guarantee that $f$ is positive in a punctured neighborhood about $0,$ since $f(x)<0$ for all negative numbers $x$ sufficiently close to $0.$ However, we do indeed have $$0\ne f'(0)=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{f(x)}{x}.$$ Applying the $\epsilon$-$\delta$ definition of limits to the function $\frac{f(x)}{x}$ will allow us to show that $|f(x)|>0$ for all $x$ sufficiently close (but not equal) to $0.$

Comment: As for your idea of differentiating my expression: it may well work, though it's far from immediate (and frankly, I'm not sure how I would go about attempting to prove it). The nice thing about my approach is that only very basic results are used, such as the zero-product principle and the definition of limits.